# Running mutiple functions in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have multiple files in multiple locations on our network where I want to delete 0 record files.  When I run my script I don't get any errors but the 0 record files aren't getting deleted.  When I run them as individual scripts they work.  I'm new to power shell script and these are my first experience with them. My code is as follows. (I'm not including the actual file path in my code)

```
Function DeleteFile1
{
  $Dir = "\\File1path"
  Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -Recurse | Where { $_.Length -eq 0 } | Remove-Item -Force
}


Function DeleteFile2
{
   $Dir = "\\File2path"
   Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -Recurse | Where { $_.Length -eq 0 } | Remove-Item -Force
}
```

Comment: You've only _defined_ the functions in the script, you're not actually running them. Either add `DeleteFile1` and `DeleteFile2` on separate lines at the bottom of your script, or [dot-source the script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#using-dot-source-notation-with-scope) and invoke the functions from another script

Comment: Mathias, thanks so much for your help.  I figured it was going to be something simple.

Comment: Great to hear it worked out for you! :) The duplicate I've linked isn't _exactly_ the same question, but the accepted answer explains both approaches to invoking functions from scripts.